# Remove child node from XML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml

I am getting some extra node in XML file which need to removed. I can do this simply using XSLT or Map though I want to achieve it using JavaScript. I want to remove the entire `<Distributors>` and `<Location>` node from input xml.

**Input XML**,

```xml
<bookstore>
    <book category="cooking">
        <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
        <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>30.00</price>
    </book>
    <book category="children">
        <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
        <author>J K. Rowling</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>29.99</price>
    </book>
    <Location>London</Location>
    <Year>2022</Year>
    <Distributors>
        <Distributor1>Ingram</Distributor1>
        <Distributor2>Amazon</Distributor2>
        <Distributor3>Company</Distributor3>
    </Distributors>
</bookstore>
```

**Expected Output xml**

```xml
<bookstore>
    <book category="cooking">
        <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
        <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>30.00</price>
    </book>
    <book category="children">
        <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
        <author>J K. Rowling</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>29.99</price>
    </book>
    <Year>2022</Year>
</bookstore>
```

I tried using DOM but using DOM it's consuming a lot of memory due to size of data. Is there any simple way to achieve it without much resources, otherwise I'll try to split the msg and then will check.

```js
var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
var y = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("bookstore")[0];
var x = xmlDoc.documentElement.removeChild(y);
```

Need suggestion from experts here.

Comment: `but using DOM it's consuming a lot of memory due to size of data` then you should do this on the server that creates the xml

Comment: How are you using the XML? Most of the time you can just ignore the nodes when processing XML. Otherwise, there are limited utilities for stream-based XML processing in JavaScript like [SAX](https://github.com/isaacs/sax-js) and the like. The browser really works with DOM. Personally, I would try the XSLT route first. Should be a relatively simple transform.

Comment: @mplungjan Thank you for your comment, Happy New Year.
Yes, that is my last option to ask source system to send the data in that format, though checking the option if they deny to make any change.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, I love to make the changes in XSLT and but my lead is not interested to use XSLT. He is asking to check in JavaScript only :(

Comment: How bad is the memory usage then?

Comment: When we process these msg then memory crossed to 60-70%. Because file size is also around 50mb+

Comment: Well, the SAX link in my comment above is a link to a JavaScript library that implements a streaming XML parser that implements the SAX2 standard. You could feed it the raw `responseText` of the response and it might be a little faster. You'd need to learn SAX though :).